# Is creating a C# generic method that accepts (nullable) value type and reference type possible?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, value-type, reference-type

I want to create a simple method that accepts both *value type* and *reference type* parameters, i.e. int is value, and string is reference.

So this is what I start with:

```
public bool AreBothNotNull<T>(T? p1, T? p2)
{
    return (p1.HasValue && p2.HasValue);
}
```

So I want to be able to use it like this:

```
var r1 = AreBothNotNull<int>(3, 4); // will be true
var r2 = AreBothNotNull<int>(3, null); // will be false
var r3 = AreBothNotNull<string>("three", "four"); // will be true
var r4 = AreBothNotNull<string>(null, "four"); // will be false
```

But the first issue I encounter is

> The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

To proceed I add a struct constraint to my method

```
public bool AreBothNotNull<T>(T? p1, T? p2) where T : struct
```

But now the method won't accept the string based calls, and gives me this error:

> The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method.

Is this possible? Or why are we prevented from doing this?

Comment: that seems a strange thing to want to do?

Comment: This is not strange, it just has a sweet smell of c++.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your problem is that you want generic type constraints that are conflicting with each other:

- `Nullable<T>` works with value types only
- Reference types are not value types

So you will need to have two overloads for your code to work:

```
public static bool AreBothNotNull<T>(T? p1, T? p2) where T : struct
{            
    return (p1.HasValue && p2.HasValue);
}

public static bool AreBothNotNull<T>(T p1, T p2)
{
    return (p1 != null && p2 != null);
}
```

Still, the following line will never compile:

```
var r3 = AreBothNotNull<string>(3, 4);
```

There is a conflict here, where the generic type argument states that the parameters are of type `string`, but the code tries to pass `int`s instead.

Comment: I would also add where T : struct and where T : class constraints to methods.

Comment: Sorry it was a copy/paste mistake for line r3, I'll update the question, "three", "four" should be the parameters.

Comment: @Sara: regarding understanding Nullable<T>, I wrote a blog post about that a while ago: http://softwareblog.alcedo.com/post/2010/02/16/Nullable3cT3e-vs-null.aspx