# Is it possible to restrict a generic parameter to just accept nullable types?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nullable type as a generic parameter possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209160/nullable-type-as-a-generic-parameter-possible)
>   [Is creating a C# generic method that accepts (nullable) value type and reference type possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003026/is-creating-a-c-generic-method-that-accepts-nullable-value-type-and-reference)

In c# I would like to restrict my generic method to accept only nullable types. Is that possible?

```
public T Method<T>() where T : somesortofnullablerestriction
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003026/is-creating-a-c-generic-method-that-accepts-nullable-value-type-and-reference and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303287/can-a-generic-method-handle-both-reference-and-nullable-value-types

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209160/nullable-type-as-a-generic-parameter-possible

Comment: That solution is not valid in my case, I don´t wan´t to restrict to struct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
public Nullable<T> Method<T>()
{
}
```